# Spring Tool Suite: How do i clean Spring Tool Suite cache (if there is one)?

Tags: maven, spring-tool-suite

Few days back I created a maven project and i'm using angularJS for view, but whenever i make changes in the html file it doesn't show up after running the project, i clean the project countless number of times but the changes still don't show up. 
But what i don't understand is that sometimes the changes show up the next day I run the project.
So is there some kind of cache that i need to delete after making new changes to my project??
I'm using STS Version: 3.3.0.RELEASE.

Thanks,
-Elysium

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your JavaScript files are not being copied over to the target directory properly.  Make sure that after you do a build in the workspace that the proper version of the JS files are in the target folder on the filesystem (i.e., look outside of Eclipse).  If the files are not correct, then your maven commands are not being completely invoked inside the workspace.

It's hard to say exactly what is going on without more information, but this sounds possible.